# Ambiguity in translating first order logic wfs to english.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

So I have some first order logic wfs I want to translate to English[From "Introduction to Mathmatical Logic" by Elliot Mendelson , exercise 2.9] , but I am skeptical whether my translations are correct.Here are my translation:

$(1)$ $(\forall x)(M(x) \land (\forall y) \lnot W(x,y) \to U(x))$ 
$(t1)$ An unmarried man is unhappy

Here $M(x)$ means "$x$ is man" , $W(x,y)$ means "$x$ is married to $y$", and $U(x)$ means "$x$ is unhappy".

$(2)$ $(\forall x)(V(x) \land P(x) \to A(x,b))$

Here $V(x)$ means $x$ is an even integer, $P(x)$ means "$x$ is a prime number", and $A(x,y)$ means "$x=y$" and $b$ denotes $2$. For me there seems to be two translations, But I am not sure which one is correct or if any of them is even correct.

$(t2.0)$ if $x$ is an even prime integer , then $x$ is equal to $2$. 
$(t2.1)$ $2$ is an even prime integer.

$(3)$ $\lnot (\exists y) (I(y) \land (\forall x)(I(x) \to L(x,y)))$

Here $I(y)$ means "$y$ is an integer" and "$L(x,y)$" means "$x \leq y$".The traslation of this one is not mine, I found it in the "solutions to selected exercises". But I am still not sure if it is the correct one (because of the $\leq$ sign having an $=$ portion with it). Someone explain to me why this is precisely the correct one.

$(t3)$ There is no greatest integer.

$(4)$ $\exists x (A^1_1(x)\land\forall y (A^1_1(y)\to A^2_1(x,y)))$

$(5)$ $\forall x(A^1_1(x)\to\forall y(A^1_1(y)\to A^2_1(x,y)))$

$(6)$ $\exists x (A^1_1(x)\land\forall y(A^1_1(y)\to(A^2_1(x,y)\leftrightarrow A^2_1(y,y))))$

Here, $A^1_1(x)$ means "$x$ is a person" and $A^2_1(x,y)$ means "$x$ hates $y$".Here are the translation:

$(t4)$ there is a person who hates everyone. 
$(t5)$ everyone hates everyone. 
$(t6)$ There is a person who precisely hates those persons who hate themselves.

$(7)$ $(\forall x)(H(x) \to (\exists y)(\exists z)(\lnot A(y,z) \land (\forall u)(P(u,x) \leftrightarrow (A(u,y) \lor A(u,z)))))$

$(t7)$ every person has precisely $2$ distinct parents.

here $H(x)$ means $x$ is a person, $A(u,v)$ means "$u = v$" , and $P(u, x)$ means "$u$ is a parent of $x$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Long comment*

Regarding 2.9(c) [your (3)], a possible symbolization of "There is no greatest integer" will be: $\forall y \ [\text {Int}(y) \to \exists x (\text {Int}(x) \land (y < x))]$, that reads: "for every Integer, there is an Integer that is greater than the first one".

This is equivalent to: $\lnot \exists y \ [\text {Int}(y) \land \lnot \exists x (\text {Int}(x) \land (y < x))]$, that in turn is:

> $\lnot \exists y \ [\text {Int}(y) \land \forall x (\text {Int}(x) \to \lnot (y < x))]$.

Now, if we have that "$\text L(x,y)$" means "$x \le y$", "$\lnot (y < x)$" is exactly "$x \le y$", and thus we get Mendelson's version:

> > $\lnot \exists y \ [\text {Int}(y) \land \forall x (\text {Int}(x) \to \text L (x,y))]$.

Consider what is the meaning of the un-negated formula: "there is an Integer that is greater-or-equal to every Integer". Clearly, this number will be a "greatest integer".

---

Regarding 2.9(b), it reads: "Every prime even integer is equal to two".

Comment: Thanks for your explanation about (2) and (3). What about my other translations? Are they correct ?

Comment: @Prithubiswas - yes, they are.